# How to read specific object from json file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to work with a json file but I can't figure out how to read just a specific object from a json file.

My current code looks like this:

```
try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync("addresses.json", "utf8");
    console.log(data);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

This works fine. However when I try to get some object from the file like this:

```
console.log(data.address)
```

It doesn't work because it is a string.

So my question is how can I read just a single object from the json file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to parse the string that you get first using `JSON.parse()`. Then you will be able to access it the way you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
const address = parsedData.address
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `JSON.parse()`, as right now, you are trying to access a property off of a `string`. However, the method will change it to an object.

```js
// Dummy JSON data
const data = `{ "address": "Stack Overflow" }`;

const json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.address);
```

This will make it possible to access the properties off of the object.

Answer (score 0):

you must convert the data into json like so:

```
    JSON.parse(data)
```

In your example :

```
    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync("addresses.json", "utf8");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).address);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
```

I hope I answered your question.
Feel free to comment if I misunderstood you or you have some questions ;)